# Cannot delete a web address through the "App Engine apps"

Tags: google-apps

When we try to delete a custom "Web address", created through the "App Engine apps" -> "maps(App Engine)", we get the following error:

We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later. (Error #1000)

Can anyone explain why we might get this error?

Thank you.